# Can a car battery provide enough power to start a stargate?

Tags: stargate, stargate-origins

I remember that powering the stargate requires a lot of energy.  Is it really possible to "jump start" the gate using an old car (as in *Stargate Origins* season 1 episode 3)?

Comment: I've voted to close. It's possible ***because we see them doing it***

Comment: There are two aspects to gate travel, opening the wormhole and dialling the coordinates. The former is powered by the gate itself and the latter required external power

Comment: In universe, yes. It's shown on screen. Out of universe, no, it's a show. Definitely vote to close. Perhaps try something like, 'is it explained why the current from a car battery is sufficient to power a Stargate?'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it is never explicitly stated stargates are constantly absorbing ambient energy from their surroundings. A staff blast, for example, hitting the gate would increase its charge level, a gate would always be slightly cold to the touch because it absorbs heat etc.

When you actually want to dial a gate in an emergency situation (without a DHD) you have to provide direct current to the gate so the ring unlocks and you can turn it (possibly a safety feature).

We see this several times in the SG-1 season 1 episode "The Torment of Tantalus", season 2 episode "Prisoners" and season 2 episode "1969" in which they actually use car, well truck batteries to provide the unlocking charge to the gate.